# Kendo UI Grid ASP.NET MVC - UI Weird

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Well I'am using Kendo UI grid inside an ASP.NET MVC Application. My goal is to remove some items on a filter A when a particular javascript event is raised by another filter B.

So, I've started with setting up a custom UI for my column CategoryId  :

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Items)
                  .Name("grid")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
    ....
     columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId, Model.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName")
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("categoryFilter")));
    ....
}
```

Somewhere before the above I've defined my javascript UI function  :

```
function categoryFilter(element) {
    console.log('Kendo UI will never run me '); // Unreachable part
    element.kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: customDataSource, 
        optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
    });
}
```

Kendo grid never call function `categoryFilter`, nevertheless an error is raised by kendo when I try to use an invalid function name, eg :

```
....
// Kendo raise an error here
.Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("functionWitchDoesntExist")));
....
```

> Question : What have I miss to make my  UI filter work?

Another solution for my issue is if I can just get by jQuery the existing filter. Something like :

```
$('#grid').find('.kendoautocompletefilter').options('.....')
```

Comment: it seems like custom filter doesn't fit with foreign key columns.Please check with telerik team.

Comment: You might want to try putting your `categoryFilter` JS function above your grid definition.  Not sure if this is the issue, just an idea.

Comment: @ mmillican56  : Thank you for your remark. Actually it was already above the grid definition.